# how do i know what Cell's button in UItableview clicked

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom Cell (subclass of UITableViewCell). Each cell view has two buttons btn1 and btn2. I set my ViewController to handle the TouchUp Inside of those btn1s.

How do I know in which cell button clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put a tag property on it. Say the left one has a tag of 1, and the right has a tag of 2.
All UIViews have a tag property, which is just an integer value.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger tag;
```

Then when you have received a button tap, you can ask what the button's tag is - 1 or 2, and you'll know which button it was.

If you want to know which index path that button belonged to, you can grab the button's superview, which should be the cell, or the button's superview's superview, if you placed it on the cell's content view (as you generally should):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[button superview];
NSIndexPath *pathForSelectedButton = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Note that the above code assumes the button was placed directly on the cell.

Answer (score 1):

UIButton has a tag property. You can set a unique value to each of your button, such as indexPath.row*2 and indexPath.row*2 + 1 if there is only one section.

And then you can add target method for each button.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

Lastly, implement buttonPressed method like

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSInteger tag = sender.tag;
    // your code here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! indexPath is not a number, so i guess what you are trying to say is to make a unique tag number from section and index value in IndexPath. Am i correct? And if that so, since number of row in a section can be various, it's not simple to come up with a formula to make unique tag number in general case.

Comment: Sorry for the error. I don't have my macbook in hand. You can use indexPath.row if there is only one section. It could be trickier for multiple sections. But I'm sure there are several ways to do it. For example, if no section has more than 1000 rows, you can use something like indexPath.section * 1000 + indexPath.row.